# forgiveness after understanding

Tags: prayaschitta

If someone vow to do this when she get this. And after vowing she came to know that after getting fulfil her wish she can't be able to fulfill her vow. So what she can do?Can she fulfill her vow before getting her wish fulfill n don't have to fulfill her vow after her wish get fulfill? Can god forgive her?? Pls answer I am in great need

Comment: Pls answer this question..

Comment: Why do you ask the same questions with different accounts?

Comment: Because I m in need nd u r nt answering ... Pls answer . if u answer my question then my prblm get solved for my life time and I am not  going to ask it anymore. Pls answer.

Comment: Kamya i think u should join a chat room instead of asking the same thing again and again..BTW to whom u made the promise? to GOD?

Comment: Discuss in this Chat Room if u wish-http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/vedanta-and-philosophy

Comment: What is the reason for unability to fulfil vow? If it is due to your work busy or anythig, we can do nothing. God becomes first then your work.

Comment: Sree charan@ pls read my question and then give me the answer .

Comment: You may discuss regarding this to  [this room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55485/discussion-on-question-by-kaamya-forgiveness-after-understanding).